# Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In Angular 5, I'd like to use the first() method as shown below:

```
this.ccService.mode.first().subscribe(mode => {
  this.mode = mode;
});
```

I have it imported like this: `import { first } from 'rxjs/operators/first';`.
I've also tried importing from `'rxjs/add/operator'`, `'rxjs/operators'`, `'rxjs'`, none seem to work.

However, it refuses to work and only gives me the error message you already saw in the title: `[ts] Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.`.

The `mode` observable:

```
private modeSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('new');
public mode = this.modeSource.asObservable();

public setMode(mode: string) {
  this.modeSource.next(mode);
}
```

I've been googling but I can't seem to find anyone with the same error, am I just not using `first()` right? Am I supposed to use `.pipe(first()).subscribe`? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html uses `observable.first().subscribe` and `observable.pipe(first()).subscribe` intermittently without clear explanation or reasoning, so I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: With RxJS 5 and with "prototype" style of operators you need to patch the Observable class with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';`

Comment: @martin that fixed it, you should make it an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR; Yes, you should use pipeable operators.

Change since [rxjs v5.5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operator-pipe-syntax) :

> The previous coding style of chaining operators has been replaced by
>   piping the result of one operator to another. Pipeable operators were
>   added in version 5.5. For a full discussion of the reasoning and
>   changes required for pipeable operators, see RxJS documentation.

And here is the [why](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/91088dae1df097be2370c73300ffa11b27fd0100/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why) :

> Problems with the patched operators for dot-chaining are:
>
> Any library that imports a patch operator will augment the
>   Observable.prototype for all consumers of that library, creating blind
>   dependencies. If the library removes their usage, they unknowingly
>   break everyone else. With pipeables, you have to import the operators
>   you need into each file you use them in.
>
> Operators patched directly onto the prototype are not "tree-shakeable"
>   by tools like rollup or webpack. Pipeable operators will be as they
>   are just functions pulled in from modules directly.
>
> Unused operators that are being imported in apps cannot be detected
>   reliably by any sort of build tooling or lint rule. That means that
>   you might import scan, but stop using it, and it's still being added
>   to your output bundle. With pipeable operators, if you're not using
>   it, a lint rule can pick it up for you.
>
> Functional composition is awesome. Building your own custom operators
>   becomes much, much easier, and now they work and look just like all
>   other operators from rxjs. You don't need to extend Observable or
>   override lift anymore.